# SMD resistor with same resistance but with different power will reduce the temperature of my PCB?

Tags: resistors, thermal, power-dissipation

I need to reduce the amount of heat generate by some resistors on my PCB.

My question is if I use a 10ohms - 2 watts - 2512 SMD resistor instead of a 10ohms - 1 watt - 2512 SMD resistor, the amount of heat generated by the 2W resistor will be higher, similar or lower than the amount of heat generated from the 1W?

So the 2W will be better than 1W, correct?

RESISTOR SPEC:

2 watts resistor: http://www.bourns.com/docs/Product-Datasheets/CRM.pdf

1 watt resistor: http://www.bourns.com/docs/Product-Datasheets/CR2010.pdf

Thank you

Comment: Why do you think that the lower-rated resistor can violate P=EI?

Comment: The amount of heat will be exactly the same. The only difference is that the 2W resistor can survive 2W of heat, but the 1W resistor can only survive 1W of heat.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams We use P = V*I since this fourm uses english and E stands for electric field not voltage

Comment: The way to reduce heat is to not put power through a 10 ohm resistor.   Unless it's for something like a dummy or brake load, you should see if you can rework the circuit to not require that.

Comment: two 5 ohm in series would result in a lower peak spot temperature, or 10 1ohms

Comment: The reason why I asked this question is all around this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X1LUo0T57oQ) , that show the different temperature on same resistance, but with different resistor sizes!

It's really clear that the size and consequently the wattage of the package have a huge influence on the heat dissipation.

So I was wondering if the same package with a higher wattage capability will also decrease the temperature.



https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X1LUo0T57oQ

Comment: The key thing to understand is the 1W and 2W are simply the amount of power they can pass. A higher wattage resistor may have better thermally conductive material (to air or a heatsink), and will likely have a larger surface area. This surface area can spread the heat more. Though, there are also different materials that can withstand more heat in the same package.

Comment: You should understand that resistors are designed to dissipate energy as heat, that is their job. As such, you cannot alter the amount of heat generated by a certain amount of resistance, as that is what defines that resistance. You can only get components that can deal with the heat better.

Comment: Please can I replace SMD resistor 621 with another resistor if yes what is the list of resistor that can replace it

Answer (score 4):

You are comparing two SMT resistors of exactly the same size (2512) 6.3mm x 3.1mm x 0.6mm thick operated at the same power level.

So the temperature rise at the PCB will be exactly the same, assuming the same layout and ambient conditions (such as air flow).

If you want to reduce the temperature rise you can either reduce the power dissipated by changing the circuit (or how it is operated) or you can decrease the thermal resistance to ambient. The thermal resistance to ambient for SMT parts is highly dependent on the PCB layout and specifications. For example, if you put the resistor close to a corner with a metal spacer mounting it to a panel and have a nice thick ground plane it may significantly reduce the PCB temperature rise. Just a couple square inches of copper connected to one or both of the ends may help a lot.

Comment: Thank you for the information, that will be very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Let me re-formulate:

1. If both resistors have the same value, amount of HEAT GENERATED in both components will be the same, Joule heat.
2. TEMPERATURE of a component, however, depends on how efficiently this heat is DISSIPATED, (transferred out of the heated element). The removal of heat happens in three ways, (1) by thermal conductance into surrounding solid materials (copper pads, across PCB), (2) by heat transfer into surrounding air, and (3) by means of radiation (that't why heat sinks are usually plated in black), by combination of them. Efficiency of all these thermal ways depends on the size of the part (surface area), and the delta TEMPERATURE with ambient. The temperature of a part rises until the dissipation of heat gets equal to its generation inside the part. Therefore a bigger part conducts the produced heat better/faster, so the equilibrium occurs at lower temperature point. If two parts have identical sizes and mounted into same environment, their temperatures will be the same.

The difference in wattage rating for both resistors (of same size) is likely due to differences in design and manufacturing technology, and the rating is based on reliability criteria - a 2W resistor will likely be less prone to failures than a 1W resistor under elevated thermal/electrical stress.

Comment: Thank you for the information, that will be very helpful!